# Множественное или единственное число существительного?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, существительные

Конфликт между трудовым и административным аспектом/аспектами...

Есть ли здесь связь между трудовым и административным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **Конфликт между трудовым и административным аспектом.**

Я когда-то задавалась подобным вопросом: "[Между вторым и третьим этажом или этажами?](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1701273-mezhdu-vtorym-i-tretim-etazhom-ili-etazhami.html)", но в приведённом  предложении нет числительного, тогда работает другое правило:

> ...перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне
>   связаны, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера: ср.: в
>   правой и левой **руке** (половине, стороне и т. п.); промышленный и
>   аграрный **переворот**; учащиеся среднего и старшего школьного
>   **возраста**; программы для восьмилетней и средней **школы** (как системы образования); в старославянском и древнерусском книжном
>   **языке**; глаголы совершенного и несовершенного **вида** (действительного и страдательного залога, настоящего и прошедшего
>   времени, изъявительного и сослагательного наклонения, первого и
>   второго **спряжения** и т. п.); существительные мужского, женского и
>   среднего **рода** (первого и второго склонения, единственного и
>   множественного числа); местоимения первого и второго *лица*; головной
>   и спинной **мозг**...

На мой взгляд, связь между трудовым и административным аспектом та же, что между промышленным и аграрным переворотом.

> В настоящее время принципиальное значение имеет разграничение ***между
>   трудовым и гражданским правом*** с точки зрения решения вопроса об
>   обязательном социальном страховании от несчастных случаев на
>   производстве и профессиональных заболеваний.

См. также таблицу "[Основные различия между трудовым и гражданско-правовым договором](https://www.eg-online.ru/article/228141/)".

*Трудовой* и *административный* - смежные понятия (достаточно их парочкой погуглить).

Answer (score 0):

**Конфликт между трудовым и административным аспектом / аспектами...**

Для проверки правильности написания желательно видеть **полный текст** предложения, смысл которого не совсем ясен. Об аспекте/аспектах чего идет речь?

Это действительно конфликт между двумя аспектами (сторонами предмета, взглядами на предмет)?

Из словаря:

АСПЕКТ, -а; м. [от лат. aspectus - взгляд]. чего и с опр. Книжн. Та или иная сторона предмета, явления, понятия; точка зрения, взгляд на что-л. Рассмотреть законопроект в двух аспектах: экономической и политической жизни. **Гносеологические и социальные аспекты** изучения языка.

Comment: Возможно, это конфликт между интересами трудового коллектива и администрации? Тогда слово *аспект* тут мало подходит.

Comment: Всё возможно. А какое конкретно слово может стоять после "аспектом / аспектами..."?  Как бы и где бы поднять вопрос о том, чтобы  нам не предлагали разбирать словосочетания или отдельные части предложения с многоточием. Как минимум должно присутствовать целое предложение.

Comment: Нужно поднять этот вопрос на Мете, Вы правы. Можно предложить написать это в Справке, в разделе "Как задать хороший вопрос?". Но вряд ли новички читают то, что написано в Справке.

Comment: Скорее всего, там идет сказуемое: Конфликт между трудовым и административным аспектом/аспектами этого закона был  устранен путем внесения поправок.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли здесь связь между трудовым и административным?

Если речь о грамматической связи, то она безусловно есть. Оба относятся к существительному *аспект*, точее это два определения при существительном *аспект*. Вопрос о числе существительного при наличии двух определений рассмотрен у Розенталя, см. [§194. Два определения при одном существительном](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm). Выбор лучшего варианта (ед. или мн. ч.) непростой и зависит от контекста, но можно сказать, что оба варианта не являются ошибкой.